# these versatile *trunks* — called *proboscis* — are incredible inspiration

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'm wondering if "trunks" in the following should be matched not with the singular "**proboscis**" but with the plural "**probosces**."

> Elephants’ trunks are both delicate and sturdy — they are capable of grasping a single blade of grass but can also carry nearly 600 pounds. And scientists argue that these versatile **trunks** — called **proboscis** — are incredible inspiration for the next generation of bio-inspired robots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I agree it should be plural, however dictionaries differ on the plural of 'proboscis'. You should be on safe ground with 'probosces'.

> proboscis noun plural proboscises also proboscides (Merriam-Webster)
>
> proboscis NOUN plural -cises or -cides (Collins Dictionary)
>
> proboscis noun plural probosces (Cambridge Dictionary)

Cambridge Dictionary, confusingly, then goes on to give another plural in an example, with no remarks or comments:

> *The four proboscides and the two bothridia are fully formed*

'pachyderms' proboscises (6 letters)' is sometimes seen as a crossword clue

Comment: OK, downvoter, what's your answer?

Comment: I upvoted your answer.